# How to get notification from azure phone gap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode6, azure-mobile-services

I am new to mobile development. I am using Xcode 6.0 and phonegap on IOS8

I have uploaded .p12 certificate on azure mobile service.

even I am able to get token after

> pushNotification.register(
>                   app.tokenHandler,
>                   app.errorHandler, { 
>                       "ecb": "app.onNotificationAPN"
>                   });

but when i send notification from azure debug, my phone unable to get the notification.

Can somebody please help me to know why i am not getting notification from azure on my iOS phone

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive a push notification you must give your mobile service the device token. With version 1.2.5 or later, you can use the client.push.apns.registerNative or registerTemplate function to do so if you are using Notification Hubs.

This would look something like so:

```
 app.tokenHandler = function (deviceToken) {
   client.push.apns.registerNative(deviceToken, ["news", "updates"]);
 }
```

Also, I'm not sure what the default behavior for the pushNotification module is, but I've always sent { "alert": "true" } in the 3rd param in addition to "ecb" as well.  (Depending on the type of push, you may want to ask for additional types.)